# Connecting Arduino Mega 2560 to Python with PyFirmata

Tags: arduino-mega, python, firmata

I am currently controlling two servos using the Arduino IDE, but now need to integrate my Arduino code into a Python script. I read about how to use PyFirmata and went through the process of uploading StandardFirmata to my Arduino Mega 2560 board after changing the samplingInterval value to 99, instead of the default 19. However, having followed the exact procedure of translating Arduino code to Python and downloading/using the correct pyfirmata package, the board simply does not react. I tested the board, the individual servos, power, etc. and have even used the ArduinoMega module in pyfirmata, but there is absolutely no reaction when using the Python code. I have looked through multiple online forums and it seems that this is a recurring issue, but no one has posted a solution (as per my knowledge) to the problem and it would be of great help if someone could help me fix this. Please let me know if you would like to see any of the code, it is very simple and I do not mind sharing it if required. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some code sure help to understand the issue. Also, you can send some predetermined commands from Python to Arduino through a serial port to make your Arduino do what it is supposed to do. You don't necessarily need PyFirmata if your case is simple servo control.